# Problema con datetimepicker en un dom

Tags: php, javascript

Buenos días amigos tengo el siguiente problema con un datetimepicker en un formulario dinámico[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí] que se incrementa, el problemas es que la primera fila se me despliega el datetimepicker per si lo doy al boton mas para clonar la fila de arriba el segundo datetimepicker no se me despliega el calendario

Html

            
            Fecha Inicio:

```
        <div class="col-xs-5">   
        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Fecha Fin:</label>
        <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker2'>
        <input type="text" name="fecha_final[]"  class="form-control" />
        <span class="input-group-addon">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
        </span>
            </div>
            </div>
          </td>
```

esta es función de datetimepicker

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
       $(function () {
            $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
                defaultDate: "<?php echo date('Y-m-d-hh') ?>",

               $('#datetimepicker2').datetimepicker({
                defaultDate: "<?php echo date('Y-m-d-hh') ?>",


            });

        });
    </script>
```

y por ultimo el javascript que me aumenta los campos del formulario

```
<script>

        $(function(){

        // Clona la fila oculta que tiene los campos base, y la agrega al final de la tabla
        $("#adicional").on('click', function(){
          $("#tabla tbody tr:eq(0)").clone().removeClass('fila-fija').appendTo("#tabla");
        });




        // Evento que selecciona la fila y la elimina 
        $(document).on("click",".eliminar",function(){
          var parent = $(this).parents().get(0);
          $(parent).remove();
        });
     });
    </script>
```

Comment: Como generas el nuevo contenido? Mediante ajax, recargando la pagina o creandolo con javascript?

Comment: con javascript es el código que esta arriba que clona la filas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando clonas un elemento, el evento del datepicker no es clonado con el por lo que tendras que indicarle al elemento clonado que es un datepicker aplicandole la funcion `datetimepicker()` otra vez sobre el elemento que tiene la clase `.date`:

```js
$(function () {
   $('.date').datetimepicker();
   
   
   $("button").click(function(){
   
   // clonamos el elemento que tiene el datepicker
    var clon = $('.form-group:first').clone();
    
    // buscamos el elemento con la clase .date para aplicarle el datetimepicker
    clon.find(".date").datetimepicker();
    
    // agregamos el picker a la lista de los calendarios
    $("#calendars").append(clon);
    
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link href="//cdn.rawgit.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/e8bddc60e73c1ec2475f827be36e1957af72e2ea/build/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script type="text/javascript" src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
   <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.9.0/moment-with-locales.js"></script>
   <script src="//cdn.rawgit.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/e8bddc60e73c1ec2475f827be36e1957af72e2ea/src/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js"></script>
      
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div id='calendars' class='col-sm-6'>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
                    <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <button>Generar nuevo datepicker</button>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            
        </script>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias Einer

Comment: Muchas Gracias Einer lo adapte con mi código y funciona perfecto, saludos desde Venezuela.

Comment: Me alegra saber que te funciona. Saludos igual desde RD.